# ajax succes function not worked

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

i' trying to send data from ajax to django.
here is my script:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#accept_all').click(function(){
      var id_list = [];
      $('#table input:checked').each(function() {
      id_list.push($(this).attr('value'));
        });
      $.ajax({
              url: "/myurl",
              type: "post", 
              data: {
                  'id_list': id_list,
                  },
              headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'}, 
              success: function(data) {
                window.location.reload();
          }});
        });
      });
```

and in my django views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def mydef(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if request.is_ajax():
                  id_list=request.POST.getlist('id_list[]')
                  for item in id_list:
                         obj=models.users.objects.get(id=item)
                         obj.Status='1'
                         obj.save()
            return HttpResponse('done!')
```

**this function works correctly and changes to obj done! but in success function of ajax that should reload page not worked**

Comment: I'm not sure that returning an http response 'done' is taken as an 200 or whatever success code.

Comment: @FedericoProvenziani what should return for access?it's not important what returned

Comment: Is not important!? I'm genuinely laughing. Try with return HttpResponse(status=204). Then if that is not the issue, add an error handler for Ajax and check the error.